# Can anyone explain about Applets and AWT?

Tags: java, applet, awt

I have recently started working on java applets.I am actually confused between the two terms, applet and awt . Please someone help me to get clear understanding of what those two terms actually mean.

Comment: they are both obsolete and out of date. Don't start working on them, unless you plan to find a job in the 1990's

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.But can I know what are applets and awt replaced by in java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWT: This stands for "Abstract Window Kit". Java's standard cross-platform GUI toolkit

Applet: Applet was designed to extend the capacity of a web browser / HTML with dynamic capabilities.

javax.swing was the replacement to AWT, though in places I believe AWT is still in use.

Applets were replaced by javascript, an entirely different programming language native to web browsers.